# gulpfile: Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile , with a default does not watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have a simple gulp file that when i have no default task it gives me an error, but when i add a default task it does not watch.

here is what I have in the file:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task( 'default', ['sass'] );

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/theme.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with gulpfile like this:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/theme.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: @SandraWillford a comma is missing in the last task. fixed it.

Comment: @SandraWillford you're welcome. can you approve the answer, as well?